# SQL Server Optimal Index on Substring?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, indexing

Running SQL Server 2008, I have a table with a few million rows of log info dump from an app. I am trying to figure out how to write the best index to get relevant info.

Table looks like this. Just a sample, the actual message data is long.

```
CREATE TABLE #Info(
    [infoID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ActionHappened] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [PartialMessage] [nvarchar](1500) NULL,
    [FullMessage] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_info] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([infoID] ASC)
      WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
            ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]

Insert Into #Info Values ( GETDATE() , 'Thread:05;D:Start;Msg:Activity A' , 'Thread:05;D:Start;Msg:Activity A abcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyv' )
Insert Into #Info Values ( dateadd( minute , 3 , GETDATE() ) , 'Thread:05;D:Start;Msg:Activity B' , 'Thread:05;D:Start;Msg:Activity B abcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyv' )
Insert Into #Info Values ( dateadd( minute , 6 , GETDATE() )  , 'Thread:05;D:Start;Msg:Activity C' , 'Thread:05;D:Start;Msg:Activity D abcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyv' )
Insert Into #Info Values ( dateadd( minute , 9 , GETDATE() )  , 'Thread:05;D:Start;Msg:Activity D' , 'Thread:05;D:Start;Msg:Activity E abcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyv' )
Insert Into #Info Values ( dateadd( minute , 15 , GETDATE() )  , 'Thread:05;D:Start;Msg:Activity E' , 'Thread:05;D:Start;Msg:Activity F abcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyvabcdegghijklmnopqrstuvwxyv' )
```

I need to select from `PartialMessage`, ignoring everything before the second semicolon, and then return `ActionHappened` and `FullMessage`. For example I want to

```
select ActionHappened, FullMessage 
from #Info 
where PartialMessage Like '%Activity D%'
```

but of course not table scan and soft-search inside each column.

All ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You should split these up into separate columns for `thread`, `start`, `activity` whatever instead of storing it in some concatenated string that is impossible to index and that you need to decompose to query. Atomicity is a requirement for even [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity)

Comment: Totaly agree with previos answer(+1). Another option can be XML. You can transform PartialMessage into a XML field, then you can create a [XML index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345121%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)(also see [Performance Optimizations for the XML Data Type in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345118%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)). Finally, you can query XML values using [xquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx).

Comment: I wish I had the ability to edit the table schema. But I don't. That's why I am here. :)

Comment: @Snowy - To be indexable these values will need to be split apart somewhere - maybe another table if you can't change the schema of the original one? The only indexing mechanism for substrings is full text indexing but you haven't really got much control over how the parser breaks your string up into words so not sure that would help much.

Answer (score 1):

Could you create an indexed view to slice the fields apart, like Martin suggests?  The following might work, but with the size of the field, it might not be beneficial.

- Create a field called **ReversePartialMessage**
- Using a trigger to populate this field with the **REVERSE(partialMessage)**
- Add an index on Both **PartialMessage** and **ReversePartialMessage** fields
- Make the WHERE clause

  where PartialMessage Like 'Activity D%' And ReversePartialMessage Like 'D ytivitcA%'

However, with the size of PartialMessage, I am not sure if the effort of these indexes would gain much.  If the field can be shortened, these indexes might be practical.  If you do create the indexes, be sure to visit the execution plan to see if they are actually used.   The optimizer might decide a table scan is more efficient than the indexes.  The work of merging the output of the two indexes, particularly with such large key values, might not yield any significant gains...